# "Sufficiently fat" Schur polynomial times Schubert polynomial is Schubert-positive

Tags: schur-functions, schubert-calculus, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

It's still open to find a combinatorial proof that for integers $k>0$ and $m>0$, a permutation $u\in S_\infty$ with its final descent at position $m$, and a partition $\lambda$ that
$$\mathfrak{S}_u(x_1,\dotsc,x_m)s_\lambda(x_1,\dotsc,x_k)$$
is Schubert-positive. However, I have a combinatorial proof (in fact a positive formula) that if $\lambda_i\geq m-k$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, then the result is Schubert positive. Is this known? I'm aware of work that claims combinatorial positivity of all Schubert-Schur products, but I've checked with the authors and they are not confident that the methods are sound, hence the problem remains open. This special case encompasses Kohnert's result that the result is positive if $k\geq m$.

As indicated in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453974/sufficiently-fat-schur-polynomial-times-schubert-polynomial-is-schubert-positi#comment1174700_453974), I am aware of Knutson and Zinn–Justin's work on separated descents, which covers the case $k\geq m$ as well as the case where $k$ is less than or equal to the first descent of $u$, but this can have $k$ be anywhere in the middle of the descents of $u$. The "fatness" allows for a reduction to the separated descents case (the result is a sum of coefficients of products of a Schur polynomial with $k$ variables with a Schubert polynomial with at most $k$ variables), which is how my formula works.

My result actually applies to double Schubert polynomials, which I'm certain is new (it doesn't give a positive formula in equivariant cohomology, but it has positive coefficients as a polynomial in $y_i-z_j$ for the product $s_\lambda(x;y)\mathfrak{S}_u(x;z)$), but I'm trying to find out if it's new in the ordinary Schubert polynomial case as well.

Comment: I'm being lazy and not checking myself, but I think this case would fall in the "separated descents" case. Knutson and Zinn-Justin have announced a solution to this https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~allenk/boston2019.pdf , and Huang has written up a much more elementary solution https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.01591 .

Comment: @DavidESpeyer No, it definitely doesn't. Kohnert's result falls under the separated descents case, but this can have the Schur polynomial's permutation have its descent in the middle of the descents of $u$. I actually have a paper under consideration that provides a separated descents result for double Schubert polynomials, so I'm certainly aware of that result.

Comment: Okay, sounds like I'm wrong then. Thanks!